# Need help logging errors from Ajax form submission

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I am working on a simple form that is sending data to a customers lead management database via their API. The form returns a 400 error when their is a duplicate email entered into the system. When this or other issues happen I need to be able to throw an error in the console and log the error in a text file within my Wordpress Child theme. I can not seem to get the error to report in the console as well as how to send the error to a txt file. If the form submits okay then everything works, I get a 200 and the lead goes in.  Here is what I have so far:

```
<form class="mbform" id="base_form" action="<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>" method="post">
<div class="field">
    <input for="base_form" id="first-name" type="text" name="base_fname" placeholder="First Name*" required><br>
</div>
<div class="field">
    <input for="base_form" id="last-name" type="text" name="base_lname" placeholder="Last Name*" required><br>
</div>
<div class="field">
    <input for="base_form" id="email" type="text" name="base_email" placeholder="Email*" required><br>
</div>
<div class="field">
    <input for="base_form" id="phone" type="tel" pattern="[(]\d{3}[)][\s]\d{3}[\-]\d{4}" name="base_phone" placeholder="Mobile*" required><br>
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="custom_action">
<div class="field submit-button">
    
        <button class="button mbgo" for="base_form" type="submit" name="base_submit">Claim Offer</button>
</div>
</form>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$('#base_form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
 
    var $form = $(this);
 
    var settings = {
          "url": "https://apiendpoint.com/api/WorkOrder/PostAllWorkOrder",
          "method": "POST",
          "timeout": 0,
          "headers": {
            "Authorization": "Bearer jTs1OCFtj5HRhYJmqRjbO35F0x0BnAmyV05hTLUzZjTbXWbfvmhhDXCp4oU8Zg9_Ec6z34n5nkCQOLRMPsK4JnM_NZiVFJGf6DRxkWQt4DzOfFhT06q2KalQrrmA5WoykVLLIE5RR8A1m34TUK37gh4E08zwC3hwW4rnQfIhez30MLDCR-PWEXTfhP5DugjzCrzoR05B15ggXt3OxoRNKxeWgcCw6Q6-E5Cl6Wlkge5iiH3DKoUqAn2tJ1m2UlXobWXSG86o3yfQsPfI7966Uy5zGU7UGB4RTD-Cz8I2U2PC7a4L-TK6UbAem2d2zfusYor81iuMcHfRCsZm60YCtGfbatuYxGXe7HCHmH6mtU8S-aGPJFhpdcyjsa7lx44_KhYzR6EsnKixgu26Wu-qnHmbKaBBKDdqZBMxrJo4tNVM9772WfjdNQpKIDfytZCWQj-iyhmerqdg9mIt3v9Ez79LKliPXXhFkgoESECKhMaHUNLX",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Cookie": ".AspNet.Cookies=3iF1xtlsAqyPyTxheHIYgFkvYtepDaZk8UnqLYbkezCdSGVSFCaQwl_9JqTJ8UJ8ytHZ5zrS-vwc3bkbwbJjjZdjn6gRKAMuUG6S2ANvUX94GoIC0-RGW_gXbr2aA-Qle4f8KnPRFKF0BEIBV0Kacxk51u7wBOyJiR7XGSVfrNq5F-fVTAnkrX4o8S0YLm7HC8WhyLgGMlpy6IhmXUplvwMbeQ7y9ZkSizGl9ETrYSr4vYP3tj7hAS-JCvsXm_UaI705bl_lo_iFdbrKaTAN9CONVV-KV1WpmGx-n3J__731wyr20_V1pBy4szbZ2rXych_Ik-b2kiVhj3zikE7q4iiL4k8wD8DiFHYQC_DnqbwFG0hKqs-YU5EEb-0TYSW3mChFUbVVJpEiJ5wxYpmO8Lni9JsNTf_baf-_QYWVRXaE5P5vnfN9gJHIm3Me6oFdvpo3YIPSm6Yci--LDUVeiLtTg10"
          },
          "data": {
            "FRANCHISEID": 1,
            "WSTicketNumber": "487260",
            "SERVICETYPEID": 0,
            "LeadSourceId": "1",
            "Note": "N/A",
            "IsLeadOnly": true,
            "Customer": {
              "FirstName": jQuery("#first-name").val(),
              "LastName": jQuery("#last-name").val(),
              "Address": null,
              "Address2": null,
              "City": null,
              "State": null,
              "PostalCode": null,
              "Email": jQuery("#email").val(),
              "Phone": jQuery("#phone").val(),
              "PhoneType": "Cell Phone",
              "PreferredCommunicationType": "phone",
              "MemberSecondaryIndexCode": "50"
            }
          }
        };

        var allData = settings.data.Customer;
        $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
          console.log(response);
                $("#error").html("<div id='message'></div>");
                $("#message")
                  .html("<h2>Contact Form Submitted!</h2>")
                  .append("<p>We will be in touch soon.</p>")
        });

        $.ajax(settings).fail(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            console.log(allData);
            var message = allData.FirstName;
                $("#error").html("<div id='message'></div>");
                $("#message")
                  .html("<h2>There was an issue with your recent submission</h2>")
                  .append("<p>" + message + "</p>")
        });
});
 

$("input[name='base_phone']").keyup(function() {
$(this).val($(this).val().replace(/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d+)$/, "($1) $2-$3"));
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. So you are asking how to handle other Status Codes that are not 200? What do you want it to do?

Comment: _"I am struggling to do both"_ is not an adequate explanation of your issue. Please edit your question to include a clear and full explanation of what the issue actually is. Point out what you've tried, what you expect to happen, when it should happen and what currently happens.

Comment: Also it looks like `.fail()` is attached to a 2nd AJAX call when it should be attached to the 1st. See More: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Also, of you want to store errors in a file, you need to do that in the back end (your PHP). Please post that part as well, if you've tried something. I would also recommend against storing the error log in the child theme since anyone would then be able to download it. Put it outside of the document root instead.

Comment: I do not have anything set up PHP. I am using Wordpress ajax file in the post.

Comment: I do not have any code yet for the PHP side of things. This is the last piece I am struggling with on where to start and how to store it to that file.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $('#base_form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $form = $(this);

    var settings = {
      "url": "https://apiendpoint.com/api/WorkOrder/PostAllWorkOrder",
      "method": "POST",
      "timeout": 0,
      "headers": {
        "Authorization": "Bearer jTs1OCFtj5HRhYJmqRjbO35F0x0BnAmyV05hTLUzZjTbXWbfvmhhDXCp4oU8Zg9_Ec6z34n5nkCQOLRMPsK4JnM_NZiVFJGf6DRxkWQt4DzOfFhT06q2KalQrrmA5WoykVLLIE5RR8A1m34TUK37gh4E08zwC3hwW4rnQfIhez30MLDCR-PWEXTfhP5DugjzCrzoR05B15ggXt3OxoRNKxeWgcCw6Q6-E5Cl6Wlkge5iiH3DKoUqAn2tJ1m2UlXobWXSG86o3yfQsPfI7966Uy5zGU7UGB4RTD-Cz8I2U2PC7a4L-TK6UbAem2d2zfusYor81iuMcHfRCsZm60YCtGfbatuYxGXe7HCHmH6mtU8S-aGPJFhpdcyjsa7lx44_KhYzR6EsnKixgu26Wu-qnHmbKaBBKDdqZBMxrJo4tNVM9772WfjdNQpKIDfytZCWQj-iyhmerqdg9mIt3v9Ez79LKliPXXhFkgoESECKhMaHUNLX",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Cookie": ".AspNet.Cookies=3iF1xtlsAqyPyTxheHIYgFkvYtepDaZk8UnqLYbkezCdSGVSFCaQwl_9JqTJ8UJ8ytHZ5zrS-vwc3bkbwbJjjZdjn6gRKAMuUG6S2ANvUX94GoIC0-RGW_gXbr2aA-Qle4f8KnPRFKF0BEIBV0Kacxk51u7wBOyJiR7XGSVfrNq5F-fVTAnkrX4o8S0YLm7HC8WhyLgGMlpy6IhmXUplvwMbeQ7y9ZkSizGl9ETrYSr4vYP3tj7hAS-JCvsXm_UaI705bl_lo_iFdbrKaTAN9CONVV-KV1WpmGx-n3J__731wyr20_V1pBy4szbZ2rXych_Ik-b2kiVhj3zikE7q4iiL4k8wD8DiFHYQC_DnqbwFG0hKqs-YU5EEb-0TYSW3mChFUbVVJpEiJ5wxYpmO8Lni9JsNTf_baf-_QYWVRXaE5P5vnfN9gJHIm3Me6oFdvpo3YIPSm6Yci--LDUVeiLtTg10"
      },
      "data": {
        "FRANCHISEID": 1,
        "WSTicketNumber": "487260",
        "SERVICETYPEID": 0,
        "LeadSourceId": "1",
        "Note": "N/A",
        "IsLeadOnly": true,
        "Customer": {
          "FirstName": jQuery("#first-name").val(),
          "LastName": jQuery("#last-name").val(),
          "Address": null,
          "Address2": null,
          "City": null,
          "State": null,
          "PostalCode": null,
          "Email": jQuery("#email").val(),
          "Phone": jQuery("#phone").val(),
          "PhoneType": "Cell Phone",
          "PreferredCommunicationType": "phone",
          "MemberSecondaryIndexCode": "50"
        }
      }
    };

    var allData = settings.data.Customer;
    var request = $.ajax(settings).done(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
      $("#error").html("<div id='message'></div>");
      $("#message")
        .html("<h2>Contact Form Submitted!</h2>")
        .append("<p>We will be in touch soon.</p>")
    });

    request.fail(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
      console.log(allData);
      var message = allData.FirstName;
      $("#error").html("<div id='message'></div>");
      $("#message")
        .html("<h2>There was an issue with your recent submission</h2>")
        .append("<p>" + message + "</p>")
    });
  });

  $("input[name='base_phone']").keyup(function() {
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d+)$/, "($1) $2-$3"));
  });
});
```

This will Assign handlers immediately after making the request, and remember the jqXHR object for this `request`.

See More: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: This is very helpful. The data is outputting in the console log as I needed now. So next step is passing the console log information to a txt file when there is an error.